# View Doesn't Change During Xamarin Forms Prism Navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

My background is WPF (with MVVMLight Toolkit) and WinForms, but I am new to Xamarin Forms and Prism.  I am trying to implement a two-step login for an app that I am porting from Swift.  In step one, the user types a customer ID (each of our customers has many employees.)  In step two, they are shown a list of users for that customer ID, and much choose their name and enter a password.

I am using Xamarin Studio 6.3 for Mac, Xamarin Forms 2.3.4.231, and Prism/Unity 6.3.0

My problem is that when I type the customer ID and click submit, the "OnNavigatingTo" code in the second login view runs, and I successfully retrieve the user list from my web service (this code is in the second ViewModel), but the second view never appears.  When I step through code, all of the business logic runs as expected, but from the user's perspective, the view never changes.  I am sure I am missing something simple, but I haven't found any help after reading through multiple blog posts on Prism navigation and looking through similar questions on S.O.

app.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("DealerLoginPage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<DealerLoginPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<UserLoginPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<SalesSummaryPage>();

        // Uncomment this section for design data
        //Container.RegisterType<ISalesDataRepo, DesignSalesDataRepo>();

        // Uncomment this section for runtime data
        Container.RegisterType<ISalesDataRepo, AzureSalesDataRepo>();


    }
}
```

DealerLoginPageViewModel.cs (step one of login - also initial view/VM)

```
public class DealerLoginPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _chosenDealer;
    public string ChosenDealer
    {
        get { return _chosenDealer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _chosenDealer, value); }
    }

    private INavigationService _navigationService;
    public DelegateCommand Submit { get; set; }

    public DealerLoginPageViewModel()
    {

    }

    public DealerLoginPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        Submit = new DelegateCommand(Submit_Clicked);
    }

    void Submit_Clicked()
    {
        NavigationParameters parameters = new NavigationParameters();
        parameters.Add("ChosenDealer", ChosenDealer);

        _navigationService.NavigateAsync("UserLoginPage", parameters);
    }
}
```

UserLoginViewModel.cs (step two of login process - navigation target)

```
public class UserLoginPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private List<string> _dealerUsers;
    public List<string> DealerUsers
    {
        get { return _dealerUsers; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _dealerUsers, value); }
    }

    private string _selectedUser;
    public string SelectedUser
    {
        get { return _selectedUser; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedUser, value); }
    }

    private string _selectedDealer;
    public string SelectedDealer
    {
        get { return _selectedDealer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedDealer, value); }
    }

    private INavigationService _navigationService;
    private ISalesDataRepo _salesDataRepo;

    public DelegateCommand Submit { get; set; }

    public UserLoginPageViewModel()
    {

    }

    public UserLoginPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, ISalesDataRepo salesDataRepo)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _salesDataRepo = salesDataRepo;

        Submit = new DelegateCommand(Submit_Clicked);
    }

    void Submit_Clicked()
    {
        // unrelated code
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        // a breakpoint here gets hit - this code runs, but related view never appears!

        if (parameters.ContainsKey("ChosenDealer"))
            SelectedDealer = (string)parameters["ChosenDealer"];

        if (DealerUsers == null)
        {
            // we have the dealership, but not the dealership's users yet. Get them asynchronously
            var getUsers = _salesDataRepo.GetUserListAsync(SelectedDealer);
            getUsers.Start();

            // set up the listview once we have the users.
            var setUsers = getUsers.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
            {
                if (getUsers.Status == System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    DealerUsers = getUsers.Result;
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

I am navigating to the second view (not the ViewModel), and the expected code in the second ViewModel is running successfully, so it seems like everything is wired up correctly.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Why is the view not changing?

*** EXTRA CREDIT ***: Does anyone know a way in my app.xaml.cs to create an if-else statement to register the appropriate repository depending on whether I am in design mode?  I have seen workarounds where you can check whether App.Current == null to determine whether you are in design mode, but apparently Xamarin.Forms 6.2 "broke" that approach...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: without a full reproduction it would be very hard to say exactly why you're running into the problem you have. I will say though you can simplify your code navigation to the UserLoginPage to `_navigationService.NavigateAsync($"UserLoginPage?ChosenDealer={ChosenDealer}")`. You can check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dansiegel/d6827a98788e76c4e313ccffe99d1993) for some tips on debugging this problem

Comment: @DanS. - that gist is very helpful - that approach helped to expose an Exception that is being swallowed at runtime.  I am seeing `System.InvalidOperationException: The current type, Prism.Navigation.INavigationService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?`.  I haven't found a quick answer, but that issue seems to be better documented at least.  Unless you have any further suggestions, I will update the post when I find a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if the code you provided is the exact code from your solution, but that sounds more like you have a typo and your `UserLoginPageViewModel` does not name the NavigationService exactly `navigationService`

Comment: @DanS. - I thought it might be that too, but this is an exact cut and paste (with a few things omitted) and I double-checked.  If I replace the async code in my OnNavigatingTo with just static test code to make a list of strings and assign it to that property, the problem goes away, so perhaps it's a no-no to run OnNavigatingTo code asynchronously, or maybe I have a bug there?  When I set the breakpoint, though, I'm getting the data I expect.  Even when the navigation works as expected (because I'm using dummy code), I still get the InvalidOperationException, so that may be a red herring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle design time/mock services vs production services there are a number of techniques that you can use. But you will want a way to easily switch between them, for this I would suggest using compiler symbols. You will want to create a new build profile in your projects for example you might create one called `Mock` and then define a symbol for that profile `MOCK`.

- One of the first things you can do is to use Compiler directives to register the appropriate service

`#if MOCK
    Container.Register<IFooService,MockFooService>();
    #else
    Container.Register<IFooService,FooService>();
    #endif`

- Another technique that you can use is to add a conditional compile to your files. This technique will keep both files in the Solution Explorer and allow you to actually name the classes the exact same (though the files themselves need to be named differently).

Your csproj file might look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Services\MockFooService.cs" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Mock' " />
    <Compile Include="Services\FooService.cs" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Mock' " />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I've never played around with anything like this, but it looks promising.  I need to call it a day shortly, but I will let you know tomorrow if I can get it working.  Hopefully Xamarin or Prism will have something built-in for this in a future revision, but your recommendation looks like it could work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked through the issue, and it is nothing specific to Prism or Xamarin.Forms; I'm just rusty on my MVVM skillset.

1) Because I am loading the data asyncronously, the view is attempting to bind to the DealerUsers property before it has been assigned a value, therefore the view is presumably throwing and swallowing a NullReferenceException and failing to load (which would be easier to diagnose if there were more visibility of what is happening.)  In the ViewModel constructor, I had to new up the list (`DealerUsers = new List<string>();`, and then rather than assigning it (`DealerUsers = getUsers.Result` in the async method, I needed to loop through the result and add each string in `getUsers.Result` to the existing (empty) list one at a time.

2) As I should have remembered, this still doesn't work, because even though the list is populated, the ListView in the View appears empty.  To fix this issue, I had to add `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;` and change the `List<string>` to an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

** NOTE ** this solved the bulk of my issue - I am awarding the correct answer to Dan S. for his help in troubleshooting and his working solution to my extra-credit question!